# calculating adjusted means from lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

How can I calculate adjusted means for a regression model with fixed and random effects? I'd like to calculate the adjusted means for a lme regression with this formula

```
mymodel <- myDV ~ experiment_condition + (1|subject_aptitude) + (1|subjects_teacher/subjects_class)
```

where myDV is the dependent variable, experiment_condition is an independent fixed effect and subject_aptitude (participants past class average) and subjects_teacher/subjects_class (classroom nested within teacher) are random effects

The ultimate goal here is to visualize this data with adjusted means because the raw means (before the random effects variance is removed) do not accurately depict the results of the LMER

Comment: Have you had a look at the lmerTest Package? It has a lsmeans function.

Comment: @Daniel, appreciate the pointer. I'd been reading about lsmeans but needed that extra confirmation that it was a good way to go. thanks again

Comment: Asking for R code is off-topic here. But you could ask how this is done (ie conceptually &/or mathematically) w/o regard for the R code. The answer may be sufficiently obvious you wouldn't need help w/ the code; alternatively, code *might* come along w/ an answer anyway.

Comment: @gung, interesting. I've read that this is a bit of a [contentious issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199677/when-to-post-on-cross-validated-over-stack-overflow) but understand why you would say so. In this case I felt that I was well within the grey area

Comment: It is a long-running & contentious issue, & I do think your particular Q does fall into a gray area. That is why I thought it would be OK w/ a slight shift in emphasis. On a different note, thanks for the respect, but you shouldn't take my rep seriously.

Comment: I don't think it's a very contentious issue if there is only one factor and the covariates are not in the causal path (I.e., mediators). The vignette "using-lsmeans" in the **lsmeans** package (another source of an `lsmeans` function) describes how lsmeans are obtained. There is evidence that **lmerTest** does not do it the same way, however.

Comment: care to elaborate @rvl? do you see the lmerTest lsmeans function as less reliable?

Comment: @ghonke -- Well, I have a slanted view because I'm the **lsmeans** developer and know exactly what it does; but in my contribution in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101375/differences-between-lsmeans-and-difflsmeans, I note that the d.f. from `difflsmeans` appear to be incorrect in the example shown.

Comment: this is very helpful info @rvl, thanks for the pointer. For us, the random effects structure only changed the means by a point or two but when I get some time i'd like to do a side-by-side comparison to check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Daniel's suggestion in the comments, I wanted to close the loop about the solution. This code did the trick

```
require(lmerTest)

lsmeans(mymodel, test.effs=NULL, method.grad='simple')
```

and the output (drawn from my real data):

```
             cond_e1 Estimate Standard Error   DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI
cond_e1  wsh     4.0   0.5568         0.0328 11.6 16.9800    0.485    0.628
cond_e1  msd     1.0   0.6201         0.0327 11.3 18.9600    0.548    0.692
cond_e1  sgl     2.0   0.6399         0.0320 10.7 19.9700    0.569    0.711
cond_e1  spc     3.0   0.6056         0.0335 12.2 18.1000    0.533    0.678
             p-value    
cond_e1  wsh  <2e-16 ***
cond_e1  msd  <2e-16 ***
cond_e1  sgl  <2e-16 ***
cond_e1  spc  <2e-16 ***
```